# CUDA version crash

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, nvidia, cudnn

I installed CUDA 11.2 and realised that's not the version I wanted... Then I uninstall it via Control Panel "Uninstall a Program" and uninstall all CUDA 11.2 stuff(but I didn't uninstall those Nvidia Nsight stuff)

After that I install CUDA 10.2, but as I key in below 2 commans, both showed me different CUDA verisons.
I'm using Windows 10, with GeForce GTX 1650.

```
> nvcc --version

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:32:27_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

But with

```
>nvidia-smi

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 461.09       Driver Version: 461.09       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P8     8W /  N/A |    134MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

10.2 and 11.2... Any idea on this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nvidia-smi` shows the highest version of CUDA supported by your driver. `nvcc` shows the version of the current CUDA installation. As long as your driver-supported version is higher than your installed version, it's fine. You can even have several versions of CUDA installed at the same time.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much!